# How to render a scalate template manually?

Tags: scala, scalate

I want to try [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/) in this way:

1. Provide a scalate template, say: index.html
2. Use scala code to render it with some data manually
3. Any template format is OK(mustache, Scaml, SSP, Jade)

But I sad found nothing to do this even if I have read all the documentation and source code I found.

In order to make this question more clear, so I have such a template `user.html`:

```
<%@ var user: User %>
<p>Hi ${user.name},</p>
#for (i <- 1 to 3)
<p>${i}</p>
#end
<p>See, I can count!</p>
```

I want to render it with a user instance `User(name="Mike")`. How to do it?

Comment: Scalate has brutal documentation: a bunch of semi-connected thoughts with no context or examples. My team had far greater productivity using the Twirl library a la carte, if you dont have time to parse the source code for scalate and figure everything out yourself.

Comment: @Azeli, I totally agree with you, and also switched to Twirl in earlier time. Thank you

Comment: It's been two and a half years and it still seems that way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following `simple_example.mustache` template:

```
I like {{programming_language}}
The code is {{code_description}}
```

You can render the template with this code:

```scala
import org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine
val sourceDataPath = os.pwd/"simple_example.mustache".toString
val engine = new TemplateEngine
val someAttributes = Map(
  "programming_language" -> "Scala",
  "code_description" -> "pretty"
)
engine.layout(sourceDataPath, someAttributes)
```

Here's the result:

```
I like Scala
The code is pretty
```

Once you get past the initial learning hump, Scalate is actually pretty nice to work with (the docs don't make the lib easy to use).